# Help to insert a new section in a TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, insert

Everyone keep writing about deleting a section. Well, I can't seem to get one added.

Currently, I am trying like this (which fails with NSInternalInconsistencyException):

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *) self.tableView;

if ([tv numberOfSections] == 1)
{
     [tv beginUpdates];
     [tv insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

     NSLog(@"Inserted.. Brace for impact.");
     [tv endUpdates];
}

NSLog(@"Section count after update: %d", [tv numberOfSections]); // Never reached
```

If I am correct, inserting a section with index 0 should place it at the top, bumping all the other sections down, right? Well, if I write out the numberOfSections right after the insertSections, there appears to be no change in the number of sections.

Any ideas?

Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, thanks to both of you.

After some juggling, I finally managed to get it working. It was a combination of both your suggestions. The new data was never inserted, but also I did not have to increase the row count for the first item inserted, but only the second.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also update your data source? You can't just update the table view without also updating the underlying data.

Comment: Yes.. hm. Yes I do, still the same exception. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the [numberOfSectionsInTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsectionsintableview) message of the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource?language=objc) class.

Comment: Well, I do a [item count] to see if there is a reason to increase the sections number, if any items are added, it returns 2, otherwise 1.

Or did you mean need to actively message numberOfSectionsInTableView?

Comment: No. I didn't mean actively messaging numberOfSectionsInTableView. I meant what you apparently are already doing: returning the right number of sections on that message implementation.